# Issue while testing multiple files upload. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm having a strange issue here. I'm trying to "fake" a files upload with "Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile". Since I've noticed that each instance of the class handles a single file, I've managed to have a loop that returns an array of instances. In this way I was thinking that I could just take that array and smack it into the body of the request.

### The testing call looks like this:

```
$this->json("patch", "api/assets/1", ["damages" => $this->prepareDamagesPhotos());
```

### While the implementation of prepareDamagesPhotos():

```
protected function prepareDamagePhotos($how_many = 3, $image_name_no_extension_or_id = "dmg")
    {
        if ($how_many > 5) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot load more than 5 damage images");
        }

        if ($how_many == 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot load 0 images");
        }

        $images = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i < $how_many + 1; $i++) {

            $path = public_path("uploads/testing/damages/images/" . $image_name_no_extension_or_id . "#0" . $i . ".png");

            $image = new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(
                $path,
                $image_name_no_extension_or_id . "#0" . $i . ".png",
                "image/png",
                filesize(public_path("uploads/testing/damages/images/". $image_name_no_extension_or_id . "#0" . $i .
                                     ".png")),
                NULL,
                TRUE
            );

            array_push($images, $image);
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

The whole thing works, but when it comes to die 'n dump the `$input->all()`, this is the output:

```
array:1 [
  "damages" => array:3 [
    0 => []
    1 => []
    2 => []
  ]
]
```

### This is not good...

I'm wondering what's wrong with this approach since passing a single instance of `UploadedFile` works like a charm. Why the array gets flushed by its values but keeps its structure? O.o

I've also tried to find a way to handle this in another way, but all that I've found was concerned on a single file upload. Which I repeat, already works like a charm.

I'm really confused about... Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another way to handle this, maybe not the proper solution but I'm open to better implementations suggestions...

Changing the method from **json** to **call** and passing the files into the fourth parameter seems to work:

```
$result = $this->call("patch", "api/assets/1", [], [], $this->prepareDamagePhotos());
```

The files does not get lost anymore in the cyberspace!